# I can get all documents but unable to retrieve single document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

EDIT:

Rookie error, I was trying to reference a document by ID but the input I was using had space at the end due to human error.

```js
const id = "kahgsdjhagsd " // should be "kahgsdjhagsd"
const usersRef = fb.db.collection('users').doc(id);
```

========

I am trying to retrieve a single document yet it indicates it does not exist, despite the fact when I run the logic to get ALL documents it is in the response

```js
    const users = await db.collection('users').get();
    users.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user.id, user.data()) // <-- Works! displays ID...
        const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.id)
        if (userRef.exists) {
            console.log("User exists")
        } else {
            console.log("User does not exist") // <-- Getting this though
        }
    })
```

Its very weird, the below works if I hardcode the ID as a string:

```js
async getUser() {
    const id = "some-id-to-a-document"
    const usersRef = fb.db.collection('users').doc(id);
    const doc = await usersRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!'); 
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data()); // <-- Getting this...
    }
}
```

But if I try to input an ID via the function...

```js
async getUser(id) {
    console.log(id) // <-- shows the ID!
    const usersRef = fb.db.collection('users').doc(id);
    const doc = await usersRef.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!'); // <-- Getting this...
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const userRef = fb.usersCollection.doc(user.id)

In the above line, You have to get the `DocumentSnapshot` using `get()` before checking the document existence.

```
const userSnap = await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.id).get();
if (userSnap.exists) {
    console.log("User exists")
} else {
    console.log("User does not exist")
}
```

And another important note, within `forEach` using async / await is not preferable as it won't give expected result always. The traditional `for..loop` would be good to get the work done.

Comment: I'm following the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data, this doesn't work. The only thing that seems to work is literally hardcoding the document ID in. even if I confirm the ID is there before it makes the call, it still won't find the doucment. It's like it wants it to be an actual string?

Comment: yes, that's a good reference to go with. In your snippet, as you are passing the `id` retrieved from firestore, it should have worked; I hope the `fb.usersCollection` has a doc with the given `ID`

Comment: just curious to know the diff between `db.collection('users')` and `fb.usersCollection`. both are referring to same collection in same database? basically why two `firestore` reference here?

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify the issue. Typically I am referencing `fb.usersCollection` from another file, but I changed my question to use the standard way but left in some of my own code.

Comment: cool; have you tried - `const  usersRef = fb.db.collection('users').doc(\`${id}\`);` ?

Comment: Hi thank you for the help... I'm going to throw my laptop thorugh a window. I found the problem. When I hard code it, it works. When I dynamically call it, it fails because the value im dynamically using as a test has a space at the end `"documentId"` vs `"documentId "`. My bad...

Comment: ha ha; glad that you got it finally!!